# Can't remove event on on();

Tags: jquery

I'm having problem unbinding event from an element which I assigned an event to using on();

Here is my JS:

```
    $(document).on('click','.reply-indicator a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var commentid = $(this).data('commentid');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '?category=getreplies',
        data:{
            "commentid" : commentid
        },
        success: function(data){
            $('.'+commentid+'subcomments').append(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

I've tried everything I could think off to remove the click event from the element
I even assigned an id attribute each iteration to each element to be able to target the element specifically because there are several:

```
$(document).off('click','#'+commentid+'indicator a');
$('#'+commentid+'indicator a').off();

$('#'+commentid+'indicator a').off('click');

$('#'+commentid+'indicator a').unbind('click');
```

But It wont loose the event in the callbackfunction or not even when I try putting this code before the ajax request but the event is still working after the callback function. Am I trying to target it correctly?

Comment: [Having a hard time replicating this issue](http://jsfiddle.net/jN7LG/)

Comment: `on` only binds the event to the element that you select (it is document in this case). And there is only one event handler through out. That's why `off` will not work here.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: I believe the problem here is different. He tries to remove click on specific element - but there will be nothing to remove, since there is no event handler there to be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a class to the elements you want the delegate on and then when you want to remove certain elements just remove the class

```
//add delegate
$(document).on('click','.reply-indicator a.onclick', function(e){
...
//remove the class from the element so it no loger matches the delegate selector
$('#'+commentid+'indicator a').removeClass('onclick');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jN7LG/2/